# assimp segfault when accesing mesh data

Tags: c++, assimp

I'm trying to load my model ([from this tutorial](https://learnopengl.com/Model-Loading/Model)) with Assimp. There is no loading error reported, but i get segmentation fault when trying to access mesh from `scene->mMeshes`. What might be reason for this?

Here is code sample:

```
void resource_manager::load_model(std::string path)
{
    model new_model;
    const aiScene *scene = load_file(path);
    new_model.meshes = load_meshes(scene, scene->mRootNode);
    //...
}

const aiScene *resource_manager::load_file(std::string path)
{
    Assimp::Importer import;
    constexpr auto assimp_flags = 0 | aiProcess_JoinIdenticalVertices | aiProcess_Triangulate |
                                      aiProcess_FlipUVs | aiProcess_ValidateDataStructure;
    const aiScene *scene = import.ReadFile(path, assimp_flags);
    if (scene == nullptr || scene->mFlags & AI_SCENE_FLAGS_INCOMPLETE || !scene->mRootNode)
    {
        //error handling is not called
    }
    return scene;
}
std::vector<mesh> resource_manager::load_meshes(const aiScene *scene, const aiNode *node)
{
    std::vector<mesh> meshes;
    for (int i = 0; i < node->mNumMeshes; i++)
    {
        mesh new_mesh;
        auto current_aiMesh = scene->mMeshes[node->mMeshes[i]];
        new_mesh.vertices = load_vertices(current_aiMesh);
        //...
    }
    //...
}
std::vector<vertex> resource_manager::load_vertices(aiMesh *mesh)
{
    std::vector<vertex> vertices;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < mesh->mNumVertices; i++)//segfault occurs here
    {
        //vertex processing
    }
    //...
}
```

Comment: Is this solved ytet?

Answer (score 0):

The code in sum looks correct but maybe there are some glitches in the data-structures.

You have to check if the indices, which are stored in the node, are valid and within 0 ... mNumMeshes-1. If you get an out-of-bounds access in the array of meshes the crash could occur,

Comment: It seems that the mMeshes array is filled with wrong data. I tried to use aiProcess_PreTransformVertices flag to "flatten" tree structure. In this case you can ignore tree structure and work on meshes directly, without indices from nodes( [assimp doc](http://assimp.sourceforge.net/lib_html/postprocess_8h.html#a64795260b95f5a4b3f3dc1be4f52e410a6e50fab95214a33996e28fae3efc7582) ). However results are the same.